# RPI 2 - Libreelec with Kodi - sound improvement

Tags: audio, kodi

I installed Libreelec (with Kodi) on the Raspberry Pi2 and I did connect it to a PC Monitor (HDMI).
PC Speakers connected to the monitor or even to the Raspberry Pi (3,5 mm jack) give me poor sound quality.

I am undecided, what to buy in order to improve sound quality.
For reason of space in my room I would like to buy a small soundbar (like Bose solo 5 or similar) but since I'm not an audio expert, I am not sure if it would be a good idea.

First of all - how would I connect the soundbar to the monitor given that I have only one hdmi port (the second one is mhl-and it seems is not working).
The Raspberry Pi also lacks of audio inputs.
I believe that a 3,5 mm jack connection would also give poor sound quality.

If is necessary I could buy a cheap audio adapters or one of those products from brand Hifiberry (DAC or AMP?) but I am confused and don't have the knowledge to choose the right thing.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want audio-output, use a GPIO-dac, like hifiberry and such. It will be a better solution than an usb-dac because less work for the Raspi.
I you want audio-in & out, I'll recommend the PiSound from Blokas. Works and sounds really well, costs you <> $ 100.-

Comment: Thank you @stephanbrun but I've already solved it by buying a Hifiberry digi+ sound card. The card must first be configured in the Libreelec OS, but it's a piece of cake. The card provides a digital output for sound and I connected it with a toslink cable to the soundbar. There was, however, one issue with the first attempt: it seems that the wifi dongle on the usb port of the Rpi used too much el.power so the sound did not work at all. After I removed the dongle and moved it to the usb hub, everything worked fine! I hope this might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: @DunavRajna how did you configured sound card with LibreElec? I am using USB sound card. can you provide me any links to the resources?

Comment: @SagarGuhe I did follow the instructions on this link: https://www.hifiberry.com/build/documentation/libreelec-installation-and-configuration/  However, I am not sure if you will take advantage of that instructions since it is refered to a different type of soundcard (not usb plug).

Comment: @DunavRajna Please make the solution you have given in comments an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.